# When i upload a new attachment and save, that file is not showing up immediately. Can i use Await and Async in this context?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am showing all the attached files in LWC component. I have a tab to upload files and one tab to show attached files. First the first time if i upload a file and see the attachments list, the new file is showing up. But during second file attachment, the attachments list is not updating with the new file. i have to refresh the url. I want the list to be refreshed when a new file is attached.

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAttachments from '@salesforce/apex/AttachmentsController.getAttachments'
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation'

export default class FilePreviewAndDownloads extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @api recordId;
    @api filesList = [];
    @api files = [];

    @wire(getAttachments, { caseId: '$recordId' })

    wiredResult({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
            this.files = data;
        }
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    previewHandler(event) {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'filePreview'
            },
            state: {
                selectedRecordId: event.target.dataset.id
            }
        })
    }
    previewexternalHandler(event) {
        //to open external files
        window.open(event.target.dataset.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are uploading the files?

Comment: Hi I am using salesforce default feature to upload files

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add some more details like where you are uploading the files, where you want to show the preview and at which line of code you are facing problem?

Comment: Hi Saroj, added my requirement. I want dynamic update of the attachents list.

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/379377/edit) the question and add the relevant HTML and Apex code as well.